# The POST method is not supported.. ROUTE::resources

Tags: laravel

Hola que tal? tengo un problema con las rutas en laravel:

en mi archivo web.php donde van las rutas tengo la siguiente ruta:

`Route::resources(['tickets' => 'TicketController']);`

Tengo varias vistas generadas, una como indice de los tickets, otra para updatear y otra para crear un ticket. Mi inconveniene se presenta al entrar a la vista de creacion del ticket, cuando quiero enviar el ticket me salta el mensaje de:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE.
```

Me gustaria saber como poder solucionar esto ya que por lo que tenia entendido las rutas resources te daban la posibilidad de utilizar todas las funciones dentro de ellas..

En mi form method tengo puesto post porque se supone que es mas seguro que el get.

Vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                   <form method="post">
                       @csrf
                       <label>Titulo:</label><br>
                       <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                       <label>description:</label><br>
                       <textarea name="description">Enter text here...</textarea><br>
                       <button type="submit">Enviar</button><br>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Ticket;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

         $tickets = Ticket::all();
        return view('tickets',compact('tickets'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {

        $ticket = new Ticket();

        $ticket->name = request('name');
         $ticket->description = request('descripcion');

        $ticket->save();

        return redirect('/tickets');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @Aprendiz listo ahi edite!

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el atributo action en la etiqueta del form, deberías tener algo así:

```
<form action="/tickets" method="POST">
@csrf
...
</form>
```

Aparte de este detalle tenés otro problema en el controlador y es que te faltan los "$" delante de request. También deberías validar tu request para evitar conflictos de integridad más adelante. Acá te pongo un ejemplo de cómo deberías hacerlo:

```
public function store(){
        $request->validate([
           'name' => 'required|alpha|min:4|max:20',
           'description' => 'required|alpha|min:4|max:20',
        ]);
        $ticket = new Ticket();

        $ticket->name = request('name');
         $ticket->description = request('descripcion');

        $ticket->save();

     return redirect('tickets');
}
```

Esto es sólo un ejemplo, deberías modificar las reglas de validación de acuerdo a tus necesidades. No obstante, checa la documentación para más detalles: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation

Comment: Oh, mala mía. Pensé que había un request en el argumento de la función y que se usaba ese.